# Recommended setup dualboot EFI

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi

Let me firstly update you on my current situation:

- HDD 1: solid state drive (GPT) with Windows 8.1 in EFI setup (no secure boot, has EFI partition)
- HDD 2: regular hard disk (MBR) with Ubuntu 13.04 alongside a documents partition in NTFS.

Now it used to be like this ever since I reinstalled Windows in EFI. In legacy mode Ubuntu booted fine (when I override boot to my HDD 2 in BIOS), although according to the Ubuntu tutorials it's not exactly recommended to have two boot methods.

I want to install 13.10 as clean as possible, and I can now decide to change setup. What can you suggest I'd do? I know it worked fine in 'hybrid' (legacy + EFI) and EFI is the way to go, but I want everything to be coherent and streamlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work either way. The trouble with the mixed-mode setup is that you need to be an expert to set it up and maintain it, particularly with two hard disks. The chain of possible options just becomes too complex to try to describe online or guide an individual through. The fact that it's working for you now means that you managed to stumble upon a working solution, but I wouldn't bet on that continuing to work when you upgrade.

In theory, there's no need to convert your second disk from MBR to GPT to boot in EFI mode. Your first disk presumably has an EFI System Partition (ESP), and when you install Ubuntu, it *should* detect that and use it to hold an EFI-mode version of GRUB 2. Even if it doesn't, you could manually install any [EFI-mode boot loader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) you like after the fact, and it should work. That said, if there are bugs in your specific firmware or in Ubuntu that would cause problems with a mixed MBR/GPT setup in EFI mode, you can convert non-destructively from MBR to GPT using [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) (which is in the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` package in Ubuntu, but I don't recall which, offhand).

Comment: Confirmed working. I can select Ubuntu from the Override Boot option (bashing ESC on BIOS splash), no need for partition table conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows8 is installed in UEFI mode, you need to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode too.

Here is how to convert your Ubuntu install in UEFI mode: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode

Comment: But shouldn't HDD2 be GPT converted to do so?

Comment: I am not sure if it is mandatory or not, as your ESP (EFI partition) is on HDD1. Please first try without GPT converting and tell me. If it fails, then convert HDD2 to GPT and reinstall Ubuntu on it.

Comment: It does work without conversion.

Comment: After upgrading Windows 8.1, i got an watermark on my desktop

"Secure boot is not configured properly ..."

I was installed Ubuntu 13.04 with EFI mode, I hope, converting my ubuntu to UEFI mode (as in @LovinBuntu's link) solve this problem.